# Exporting obj with no UV smoothing?

Tags: texturing, uv, obj

I want to export a model with uvs as an obj. Currently blender smooths uv charts (islands) at the seams, I don't wan that, I want a hard edge between each region.

i.e if this is my model projected onto the texture:

[image]

I want a hard/immediate transition between the boundaries of each of these regions when they are mapped back to the model. Currently, because blender tries to smooth the transition, I see this:

[image]

Those fuzzy edges are a problem. I want hard lines.

Comment: What do you mean it "smooths UV charts"? If you reimport it, are the UVs different?

Comment: Could this be smoothing automatically done with the program you are loading the .obj into? As far as I'm aware, Blender doesn't smooth UV's, but don't quote me on that. Providing the .blend file could help.

Comment: hello please pack your images and share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I realized the problem was on the custom renderer I was writing and not with the blender data, sorry about that. I was redering per vertex uvs rahter than separating all vertices into triangles with indepenent uvs.